# How can I combine two fast R-CNN models for object detection?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection-api

I am working on object detection in video, and I want to train two fast R-CNN models on two different types of data (for example RGB and optical flow) then combine these models in one network.

I trained the model in one type of data, but I have no idea how can I combine the both type of data.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are two-stream CNN architectures. As for example described by [Peng and Schmid in Multi-region two-stream R-CNN for action detection](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/rg/papers/peng16eccv.pdf). There is a large variaty of implementations but you will need to retrain your two-stream model with optical flow and image data.